# SQL Server: Is it possible to get procedure or table creation and last alter date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, metadata

SQL Server: is it possible to get procedure or table creation and last alter date?

If it is then how do to it?

SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date 
FROM sys.tables

SELECT name, create_date, modify_date 
FROM sys.procedures
```

The system catalog views in the `sys` schema are present in SQL Server 2005 and up, and provide a wealth of (metadata) information about the database objects.

Check out the MSDN / SQL Server Books Online docs on [Querying the SQL Server System Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082.aspx) for a lot more details and information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take things to the next level and implement a custom schema change tracking solution you can do so by using DDL Triggers.

Take a look at [Using DDL Triggers in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-ddl-triggers-in-sql-server-2005-to-capture-schema-changes)

It is common to use such techniques in order to record what has changed and to even block/rollback changes of an undesirable nature.